# Extracting first frame of ts segment from HLS Stream(m3u8)

Tags: http-live-streaming, mpeg2-ts, mpeg-2, transport-stream

I want to extract first video_frame(image) from ts segments. In my manifest file m3u8 iframe tag is not coming. Can anyone suggest how to extract first video_frame(image) without downloading complete ts segment.

Comment: Did you eventually firgure it out?